# Android database creation

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating a android application where I need to create the database in which data comes from excel file on first run when the application starts.

The problem is where should I keep the file and how do I access it in my android application or there is another method to create the database from excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use assets folder of your application. It allows you to store files there and access them through [`AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). It has `open(String filename);` method which returns you `InputStream` to a file from `assets` folder.